# setTimeout is not being called(?)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The issue was my array was [[][][]] instead of [[]] : /

This is my Script

```
function loopobject(array) {
    var me = this;
    this.array = array;
    this.loop = function() {
        counter = 0;
        while(array.length > counter) {
            window[array[counter]]('arg1', 'arg2');
            counter++;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){ me.loop() }, 100);
    }
}

var loopinstant = new loopobject(array);
window.onload = loopinstant.loop();
```

The problem arises after the first iteration. I don't know exactly the problem but I'm wondering if its due to the fact this is inside an object, and once the function is recreated it doesn't remember the array?

Comment: Don't change the question. You can add to it, but when you modify the original, the answers no longer make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Passing a string to `setTimeout` causes it to be `eval`ed in global scope.
In addition to being needlessly slow, that means that it won't see your local variables, including the `loop` variable.

Instead, you should pass a function itself to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() { loop(array); }, 100);
```

Also, the `loopobject` doesn't actually have a `loop` property that you can call later.
To make a property, change it to `this.loop = function(...) { ... }`.

Note that the `setTimeout` callback won't be called with the correct `this`.
You'll also need to save a copy of `this` in a local variable.

Finally, your `window.onload` code will *call* `loop`, then assign the result to `onload`.

Correcting these issues, your code turns into

```
function loopobject(){
    var me = this;
    this.loop = function(array){
        counter = 0;
        while(array.length > counter){
            window[array[counter]]('arg1', 'arg2');
            counter++;
        }
        setTimeout(function() { me.loop(array); }, 100);
    };
}
var loopinstant = new loopobject();
window.onload = function() { loopinstant.loop(array); };
```

Comment: I might have oversimplified it a bit, because I realized my loop was actually getting the array from the object. but for whatever reason its still not playing nice : / I did your suggustions though. I'm glad I got away from the eval function, greatly appreciate it

Comment: @Sam: Your problem is probably `counter = 0`.  That runs for each _call_; you may need to move it into the outer function.

Comment: that actually makes sense, let me try it. No the apparently it still isn't a function. I'll try changing the array into the outerfunction

Comment: mah, It doesn't make a difference since both are stored in the object. I'm not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: I have no idea what your second sentence said.

Comment: REGARDLESS! With your help and continued willingness to give support I have completed it. great success. the me.loop was a necessity. I changed the array to actually be the function instead of storing just a string. do you think that is innefficient? I greatly appreciate the time you took out for me :)

Comment: the problem was that the array was actually [[][][][]] instead of [[]]

Comment: @Sam: Putting the functions themselves in the array is a much better idea.  For one thing, it avoids filling the global namespace.

Comment: I appreciate the input! definitly excited about finishing up this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
setTimeout("loop()", 100);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function() { loop(array); }, 100);
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight on the eval, I didn't even know I was using it