# Why does setTimeout behave this way in my stream implementation?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, node-streams

The final line of this code successfully calls the _read method of a custom Duplex stream in node.

```
const timeContext = new TimeContext(sampleRate);
const input = new InputStream(timeContext); // Stream.Readable
const throttle = new Throttle(sampleRate); // Stream.Transform

const stackSource = [];

const stack = new StackStream(stackSource); // Stream.Duplex

input.pipe(throttle).pipe(stack);

stack.read(); // This will call the _read method of StackStream
```

Adding setTimeout to delay the stream.read() call, setTimeout's callback does NOT get called:

```
const timeContext = new TimeContext(sampleRate);
const input = new InputStream(timeContext); // Stream.Readable
const throttle = new Throttle(sampleRate); // Stream.Transform

const stackSource = [];

const stack = new StackStream(stackSource); // Stack.Duplex

input.pipe(throttle).pipe(stack);

setTimeout(() => {
    stack.read(); // This callback never gets called
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Does `stream.read()` gets called and does nothing or it doesn't get called at all?

Comment: The callback does not get called. I think a fiddle would be hard as this is node-specific (streams are part of node core)

Answer (score 0):

It definitely does get called but something else is erroring

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('We got here');
    stack.read(); // This is what is crashing in your code
    console.log('We don\'t get here');
}, 1000);
```

It is just not behaving as you expect because some other error is occurring. Look in the console to see what errors are raised.

Comment: If it were definitely called, wouldn't it hit my breakpoints?

Comment: Your syntax for a timeout is correct so it should. Are you sure that block is being executed? Put a break point on the setTimeout setup part.

Comment: setTimeout is being called. The callback that is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, read() function is a local property of the stack object and the setTimeout is not able to see this local property of stack object. That's why it's behaving in such a way.

Refer this solution for reference,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536268/10371717

Comment: Even if I remove that line and replace with another line - i.e. console.log('Callback executed') - the callback is not getting called. This suggests that the stack object itself can be discounted as a cause of the behaviour.

Comment: only reason when a setTimeout or any callback function doesn't execute is that 
there is always something going on the CPU and the stack is not getting cleared due to which the CPU is not making a call to the setTimeout.

Callback functions only execute when the stack gets empty.